# Changing Icon class of a button in SENCHA TOUCH 2

Tags: javascript, css, html, button, sencha-touch-2

I want to change a button's icon class (iconCls:'arrow_down') to another icon class (iconCls:'arrow_up')  when the button gets tapped. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Every property in a Sencha component automatically gets its getter and setter functions: you only need to call `setIconCls()` on the button to change the icon.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    iconCls: 'arrow_down',
    listeners: {
        tap: function() {
            if (this.getIconCls() === 'arrow_down') {
                this.setIconCls('arrow_up');
            } else {
                this.setIconCls('arrow_down');
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=bps#fiddle/bps